# Aggregating the table from many rows to one

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have a table with data as follows:

```
Name     opening     receipt     transfer     closing
abcd      1000         40            30          1010
efg       256          109           219         146
hjk       9356         210           210         9356
mnp                                 2000
```

I need is a result like this -

```
opening_abcd   receipt_abcd   transfer_abcd   closing_abcd   opening_efg   receipt_efg .....
 1000            40               30              1010          256            109    .....
```

What I have tried till now is to create multiple views one by one having the one row values like -

```
select opening opening_abcd, receipt receipt_abcd, transfer transfer_abcd, closing closing_abcd 
  from this_table 
 where name = 'abcd'
```

and similarly for others and then I have merged them together by using JOIN.

Is there a solution possible if I can select all of them in one query or any other way which is better than mine?

Comment: Do you have a finite, defined, set of values from the `name` column that you want to pivot on? I'm also not sure how you can "merge them using join". You would surely have to UNION the results together?

Comment: You're using Oracle 11g which has a built-in PIVOT operator. See http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php on Tim Hall's excellent site.

Comment: @Ben: Actually I am having 4 rows that means 4 different 'name values.'

Comment: @Ben: I can use natural join on the basis of a common column. right?

Comment: @Colin 't Hart & Ben : I have used 'pivot' method and it worked wonderfully fine for me, means when I am running it in sql developer as a query, it works fine, but when I am creating a view using the same statement, it throws the error as 'unexpected token ! near pivot......', so why it is throwing the error there.

Comment: Can you post what you have?

Comment: @colin: The error says ::  ""Error parsing sql:unexpected token near *!* in the following: pivot*!*(sum(op_stock) op_stock, sum(receipt) receipt, sum(transfer) transfer, sum(cl_stock) cl_stock FOR (fuel_name) IN ('LIGNITE' as lig, 'LDO' as l, 'HFO' as h, 'DM WATER' as dmw))""

Comment: Why do you have `*!*` in there?

Comment: I have posted the code. That's all it is. 
It does not have any thing in between. 
The same code is running nicely with sqldeveloper.